# Syncfusion Open URL in Menu Item in a new Tab

Tags: syncfusion

I have a Menu in Syncfusion Angular. The Menu Item should navigate to an URL in new tab. It is opening in same tab by overriding the website. How to acheive this.

```js
@ViewChild('sidebarMenuInstance')
  public sidebarMenuInstance: SidebarComponent;
  @ViewChild('menu')
  private menuObj: MenuComponent;
  public menuItems: MenuItemModel[] = [    
    {
      text: 'Menu Item',
      iconCss: 'icon',
      items: [
        {
          text: 'Link', iconCss: 'icon-picture icon', url: 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf',         
        }
      ],
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  private beforeItemRender(args: MenuEventArgs): void {
        if (args.item.url) {
            // To open url in blank page.
            args.element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
```